# How to paste 2 lists (of equal length) without using a loop to form a new list

Tags: r, list, paste

Say I have two lists:

```
  a = list(1,2)
  b = list("x","y")
        #a
        #[[1]]
        #[1] 1

        #[[2]]
        #[1] 2

        #b
        #[[1]]
        #[1] "x"

        #[[2]]
        #[1] "y"
```

I would like the following result:

```
        #[[1]]
        #[1] "1x"

        #[[2]]
        #[1] "2y"
```

I tried the following:

```
  lapply(a, paste, b)
```

But the result was not what I expected:

```
        #[[1]]
        #[1] "1 x" "1 y"

        #[[2]]
        #[1] "2 x" "2 y"
```

I wonder if there is any way to get the desired result - without resorting to any added package or loop.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one suggestion:

```
as.list(paste(a,b, sep=""))
[[1]]
[1] "1x"

[[2]]
[1] "2y"
```

Answer (score 0):

jigr's answer is correct but I wanted to address your attempted solution.  You were at the 1 yard line, run it in for the touch down.  You didn't supply the separator to lapply so paste uses the default `" "`.  Either supply that separator (`sep=""`) or even better use `paste0` (available with R version <= 2.15) which defaults to the `""` separator.

```
a = list(1,2)
b = list("x","y")

lapply(a, paste, b, sep="")
lapply(a, paste0, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Good to know paste0() because I do sometimes forget to include sep="" when I use paste(), which has given me problems and undesired results in the past :)